# Javascript replaceChild doesn't show the message

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have this code

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="it">
        <head>
        <script>
        function insertAfter(newNode, referenceNode) {
            referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling);
        }
        
        
        function writeMess(node, mess){
         elementEx= document.getElementsByTagName("br").length;
         if(elementEx < 5){
          newerrmess = document.createTextNode(mess);
          node.replaceChild(newerrmess, node.firstChild);
          br = document.createElement("br");
          insertAfter(br, node);
         }
        }
        
        
        function Add(){
         try{
        
          writeMess(nodoMessErr1, "");
          var capsule = parseInt(nodoCapsule.value);
        
          /* Check correct values */
          if(!isNaN(capsule)){
           totcapsule = capsule;
          }
          else{
          /* Err Mess */
          writeMess(nodoMessErr1, "Error Mess 1");
          return;
           }
         } 
         catch( e ){
          alert("Aggiunta " + e);
          return;
         }
        } 
        
        var nodoAdd;
        var nodoCapsule;
        var nodoMessErr1;
        var totcapsule;
        
        
        /* Core function */
        function gestoreLoad(){
        
        try{
        
         nodoAdd = document.getElementById("aggiunta");
         nodoCapsule= document.getElementById("capsule");
         nodoMessErr1 = document.getElementById("adderr");
        
         
         nodoAdd.onclick = Add;
         nodoCapsule.value = "";
        
         var TextNodeErr_1= document.createTextNode("");
         nodoMessErr1.appendChild(TextNodeErr_1);
        
        
         }
         catch(e){
          alert("gestoreLoad " + e);
         }
        }
        
        
        
        window.onload = gestoreLoad;
        </script>
        </head>
        <body>
         <span id="adderr"></span>
         
         <input type="text" id="capsule" /> 
         <input type="button" id="aggiunta" value="Add"/> 
         
        
        
        </body>
        </html>
```

Function writeMess works as a "writer" of messages (textnode) to append as a child of span and put after span a "< br >"

Look the "Add" function, my program works like when the user put NaN values in "nodoCapsule.value" shows an error message (default "") that alerts him.

I try to press the button (id="Aggiunta") writing NaN values in it, but no message is shown (only a " < br > " is created but no text before it)

I don't know why, any solutions?

EDIT -- It depends from browser, other browser show me the error message but continue to create "< br >". I would like only one "< br >" when the error message is shown. And no message and no br where the message it's not shown.

Comment: thank you @T.J.Crowder I edited just now. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to check whether there is already a `br` tag or not

You can check by

```
if (node.nextElementSibling.tagName.toLowerCase() !== "br") {
     // add br
}
```

Working example

```js
function insertAfter(newNode, referenceNode) {
    referenceNode.parentNode.insertBefore(newNode, referenceNode.nextSibling);
}


function writeMess(node, mess){
    elementEx= document.getElementsByTagName("br").length;
    if(elementEx < 5){
        newerrmess = document.createTextNode(mess);
        node.replaceChild(newerrmess, node.firstChild);
        if (node.nextElementSibling.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'br') {
            br = document.createElement("br");
            insertAfter(br, node);
        }
    }
}


function Add(){
    try{
        debugger;
        writeMess(nodoMessErr1, "");
        var capsule = parseInt(nodoCapsule.value);

        /* Check correct values */
        if(!isNaN(capsule)){
            totcapsule = capsule;
        }
        else{
        /* Err Mess */
        writeMess(nodoMessErr1, "Error Mess 1");
        return;
      }
    }   
    catch( e ){
        alert("Aggiunta " + e);
        return;
    }
}   

var nodoAdd;
var nodoCapsule;
var nodoMessErr1;
var totcapsule;


/* Core function */
function gestoreLoad(){
debugger;
try{

    nodoAdd = document.getElementById("aggiunta");
    nodoCapsule= document.getElementById("capsule");
    nodoMessErr1 = document.getElementById("adderr");


    nodoAdd.onclick = Add;
    nodoCapsule.value = "";

    var TextNodeErr_1= document.createTextNode("");
    nodoMessErr1.appendChild(TextNodeErr_1);


    }
    catch(e){
        alert("gestoreLoad " + e);
    }
}



window.onload = gestoreLoad;
```

```html
<body>
         <span id="adderr"></span>
         
         <input type="text" id="capsule" /> 
         <input type="button" id="aggiunta" value="Add"/> 
         
        
        
        </body>
```

Comment: very thanks !! Why do you use toLowerCase() function?

Comment: @JustAnotherSimpleProgrammer__ - It's probably a degree of paranoia. In a DOM built via HTML, the tag name will reliably be `BR` (in all caps). In a DOM built via a correctly authored and delivered XHTML file (very rare; some are correctly authored, but few are correctly delivered), it would be `br` (in lower case). So using `tagName.toLowerCase()` works in both HTML and XHTML. (I do the same thing, except I do `toUpperCase()` and compare against the all caps version, since calling `toUpperCase()` on a string that's already upper case is *slightly* faster and I'm very silly. :-) )